# Laravel: Redirect to upgrade page from every link if trial period ended

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I am new to Laravel framework. I have added the 30 day free trial functionality. At the end of free trial users are asked to upgrade the membership. After 30 days if user try to login, he is automatically redirected to the upgrade page and he is logged in. He is logged in so that upgrade can be determined to which user we are upgrading. But after logged in he is currently on the upgrade page and can navigate to any page.

I just want that if tries to navigate to other pages then he should be redirected to the upgrade page.

For this I can add the check and redirection code to each and every route and controller action but I don't want to do that. Is there any other way to perform this task where I have to write the check only once and it will work on all the pages.

This is the code of my check:

```
if($settings->free_registration && Auth::user()->role =='registered')
{
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $create_date = strtotime($user->created_at);
    $current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
    $datediff = $current_date - $create_date;
    $date_difference = $datediff / (60 * 60 * 24);
    $user_name = $user->username;
    if($date_difference > 30){
        return Redirect::to('user/'.$user_name.'/upgrade_subscription')->with(array('note' => 'Your trial period has ended', 'note_type' => 'error'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the middleware here. Put all your "trial check" code into a middleware and group all the routes except login for this middleware. Hopefully this will do the trick.

Take a look:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#defining-middleware

Comment: sorry i dont know how to add middleware and group them with the routes but i will do some R&D on this. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) for this:

> Of course, **additional middleware** can be written to perform a variety
>   of tasks besides authentication. A CORS middleware might be
>   responsible for adding the proper headers to all responses leaving
>   your application. A logging middleware might log all incoming requests
>   to your application.

Your middleware would check if the user has a valid license and redirect somewhere else if that isn't the case.

Comment: sorry i dont know how to add middleware and group them with the routes but i will do some R&D on this. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You could take your code put it in a middleware provider called `CheckSubscription` register it to the application using an alias under the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //other middlewares
    'subscription' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckSubscription::class,
]
```

And according to the way you set up your `routes` file (white `Route::group`s) or if you are using `__constructor`s in classes to check middleware you could register the alias you provided.

More information about [Laravel Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) Can be found here. Hope it's somewhat clear!